# Google Apps Script: GeoCode on Google Form submissions

Tags: google-apps-script, geocoding, google-forms

Previously I found and copy the script below for GeoCode tagging

```
function doGet() {
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}
function getLoc(value) {
var destId = FormApp.getActiveForm().getDestinationId() ;
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destId) ;
var respSheet = ss.getSheets()[0] ;
var data = respSheet.getDataRange().getValues() ;
var headers = data[0] ;
var numColumns = headers.length ;
var numResponses = data.length;
var c=value[0];
var d=value[1];
var e=c + "," + d ;
  if (respSheet.getRange(1,numColumns).getValue()=="GeoAddress") {
  if (respSheet.getRange(numResponses,numColumns-2).getValue()=="" && respSheet.getRange(numResponses-1,numColumns-2).getValue()!="" ){
respSheet.getRange(numResponses,numColumns-2).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+7", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
respSheet.getRange(numResponses,numColumns-1).setValue(e);
var response = Maps.newGeocoder().reverseGeocode(value[0], value[1]);
f= response.results[0].formatted_address;
respSheet.getRange(numResponses,numColumns).setValue(f);
}
    else if (respSheet.getRange(numResponses,numColumns-2).getValue()=="" && respSheet.getRange(numResponses-1,numColumns-2).getValue()=="" ){
respSheet.getRange(numResponses,numColumns-2).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+7", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")).setFontColor("red");
respSheet.getRange(numResponses,numColumns-1).setValue(e).setFontColor("red");
var response = Maps.newGeocoder().reverseGeocode(value[0], value[1]);
f= response.results[0].formatted_address;
respSheet.getRange(numResponses,numColumns).setValue(f).setFontColor("red");
}
else if (respSheet.getRange(numResponses,numColumns-2).getValue()!=""){
for (i = 0; i < numResponses; i++) {
if (respSheet.getRange(numResponses-i,numColumns-2).getValue()=="") {
respSheet.getRange(numResponses-i,numColumns-2).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+7", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")).setFontColor("red");
respSheet.getRange(numResponses-i,numColumns-1).setValue(e).setFontColor("red");
var response = Maps.newGeocoder().reverseGeocode(value[0], value[1]);
f= response.results[0].formatted_address;
respSheet.getRange(numResponses-i,numColumns).setValue(f).setFontColor("red");
break; }
}
  }
}
  else if (respSheet.getRange(1,numColumns).getValue()!="GeoAddress") {
//create labels in first row
respSheet.getRange(1,numColumns+1).setValue("GeoStamp");
respSheet.getRange(1,numColumns+2).setValue("GeoCode");
respSheet.getRange(1,numColumns+3).setValue("GeoAddress");
//fill data for first respondent
if (numResponses==2) {
respSheet.getRange(numResponses,numColumns+1).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+7", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
respSheet.getRange(numResponses,numColumns+2).setValue(e);
var response = Maps.newGeocoder().reverseGeocode(value[0], value[1]);
f= response.results[0].formatted_address;
respSheet.getRange(numResponses,numColumns+3).setValue(f);
}
else if (numResponses > 2){
respSheet.getRange(numResponses,numColumns+1).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+7", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")).setFontColor("red");
respSheet.getRange(numResponses,numColumns+2).setValue(e).setFontColor("red");
var response = Maps.newGeocoder().reverseGeocode(value[0], value[1]);
f= response.results[0].formatted_address;
respSheet.getRange(numResponses,numColumns+3).setValue(f).setFontColor("red");
}
}
}
```

And in html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>
(function getLocation() {
if (navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
}
})()
function showPosition(position) {
var a= position.coords.latitude;
var b= position.coords.longitude;
var c=[a,b]
getPos(c)
function getPos(value) {
google.script.run.getLoc(value);
}
}
</script>
<body>
<p> GeoCode Entered </p>
</body>
</html>
```

But I noticed the GeoCode script will record the location not based on the submission of the exact respondent, but instead from the latest form submission recorded in the Google Spreadsheet. So, if there are 4 person filling the Google Form at the same time, and clicking the GeoCode link at nearly the same time, the chance of the GeoCode for each response is mixed-up are very high.

Is there a way to modify the script so the GeoCode (which recorded in a Google Spreadsheet) will follow the exact response?

What I want is once the GeoCode link is clicked, the GeoCode record will follows the exact respondent's response.

I hope you can understand my question.